# Color Picker event for input field update but on drag end

Tags: jquery, color-picker

Following is a part of iris colorpicker js code.

```
form.find('.my-colorpick').iris({
    change: function( event, ui ) {
        var input = $(this);
        input.parent().find( '.my-colorpickpreview' ).css({ backgroundColor: ui.color.toString() });
        input.val(ui.color.toString());
        input.trigger('keyup');
    },
    hide: true,
    border: true
})
```

On clicking the input field a colorpicker window appears and on dragging in that color window, the corresponding hex color value gets populated to the input field. This is what I have now.

Now I have to write an ajax function when the input value is updated. i.e, when the color is selected from the color window, the input field gets updated and I have to use that value for something else.

The issue is the event fires and sends ajax multiple times when I drag through the colors in the colorpicker window. Is there a way I can trigger the event only when the drag stops and input field value get updated so that only one ajax function is called ?